# Making Graphic Magick detect Ghostscript for reading pdf on Windows. How to change Ghostscript invocation name on WINDOWS CMD to 'gs'?

Tags: windows, cmd, path, ghostscript, graphicsmagick

My OS is Windows 10. *What I did for Ghostscript installation*:

- I installed Ghostscript (v9.53.3)
- I added Ghostscript bin folder location to my environment PATH variable. (C:\Program Files\gs\gs9533\bin)
- I restarted my machine.

After this step, my cmd is able to recognize "gswin64c" command. However, "gs" is not recognized. According to Ghostscript examples, the 'gs' command should work. **What must I do to make "gs" command recognized?** Should I be worried here?

*Now, to my Graphics Magick Problem:*

I am also using Graphic Magick v1.3.36 (GM) on my machine. **My GM does not have the delegate for pdf format even after I installed Ghostscript as mentioned above**. As seen in this error which shows every time I try to convert a pdf file to images using gm.

> C:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.36-q16\gm.exe convert: No decode delegate for this image format (file1.pdf)

**My suspicion is that the 'gs' command is not recognized in windows and this is causing GM to be unable to detect Ghostscript**.

I would value any suggestion of how to make GM work with ghostscript on my windows machine. Thank you.

**UPDATE (5th March 2021)**
I found out that changing the command to gs for Ghostscript does not fix GM's pdf delegate problem -- GM still cannot detect Ghostscript!! My suspicion above is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with "GM's pdf delegate problem" too. And I found out that **GraphicsMagick uses the Ghostscript Fonts (also known as "URW Fonts") to support the standard set of Adobe Postscript fonts like "Helvetica" and "Times Roman".**
Download fonts from here [Ghostscript Fonts](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gs-fonts/) and paste downloaded folder **fonts** to the folder with Ghostscript files **C:Program Files\gs\gs9.27**. [Here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-windows.html) you could find more information.
[image]

Comment: Did this work for you? I pasted the font folder but it still does not work. I am still getting, "No decode delegate for this image format "

Comment: In your bin folder (C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin), did you keep your exe file names as "gswin64.exe" and "gswin64c.exe"? Because on my windows terminal, "gs" is a not found command, but "gswin64" and "gswin64c" are valid commands. In the docs, "gs" is the usual command but on my PC it is different. Could this mistmatch of name be a problem?

Comment: On my terminal I have no problem with 'gs' command, it works. But I have gs.exe in my bin folder. What installer did you use? I use the older version of Ghostscript, from this link https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs952. Downloaded gs952w64.exe, then launched this installer, added environmental variable C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin, added fonts folder and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

After installing ghostscript and adding it's path to environment variables and checking it by running `gswin64c` command.

Update the delegates.mgk file present at `C:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick-1.3.34-Q16`

The delegates.mgk entry looks somewhat like this by default-

`<delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command='"@PSDelegate@" -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dMaxBitmap=50000000 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=@GSEPSDevice@ "-sOutputFile=%o" -- "%i" -c quit' />`

Note the `@PSDelegate@` env variable in the command, Just find and replace all the `@PSDelegate@` with the path `gswin64c` at all places. After this Graphic Magick will start delegating the tasks to Ghostscript.

Also there's a issue with Graphic Magick v1.3.36 for windows, as mentioned by one of the maintainers [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/support-requests/41/#7ecd/beb0)
So try installing an older version.

A similar issue has been explained on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69115086/6279450) as well.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe the solution was something so simple. Is it necessary to do the same thing on linux?