# gm.exe convert: No decode delegate for this image format (input.pdf)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, imagemagick, ghostscript

While trying to use graphic magic version 1.3.36 in windows server

```
magick.exe -density 168x168 -quality 76 -compress JPEG "input.pdf" "output.png"
```

In GM I also installed GhostScript and used the following:

```
gm.exe convert "input.pdf" -density 168X168 -quality 76 -compress JPEG "output.jpeg"
```

getting the error `gm.exe convert: No decode delegate for this image format (input.pdf)`

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This one isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable The question falls under the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers", which is not off-topic. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Which of the tools is used primarily **for** programming?

Comment: @IInspectable I think imagemagic/graphicmagick is very common among ML task involving PDFs. I have encountered this at various professional tech jobs over the course of my career.

Comment: @kas ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick are general-purpose tools. They are not **primarily** used by programmers and certainly not for programming. Questions about usage and issues with those tools should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). They are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Questions about their programming interfaces would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gm.exe convert: No decode delegate for this image format (input.pdf)`

This generally means Imagemagick is not able to find Ghostscript.
Adding GhostScript Binaries- "gswin64c.exe" should work.
However, another way could be to modify the **delegates.mgk** file to have the binary for PSDelegate.

The Delegates.mgk entry looks somewhat like this by default-

`<delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command='"@PSDelegate@" -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dMaxBitmap=50000000 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=@GSEPSDevice@ "-sOutputFile=%o" -- "%i" -c quit' />`

Note the `@PSDelegate@` env variable in the command,
Just find and replace all the `@PSDelegate@` with the path `gswin64c`.

Note: Ghostscript bin directory should exist inside the system path for this to work.
Voila!

Comment: Also, GraphicsMagick version 1.3.36 for Windows has some issues (https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/support-requests/41/#7ecd/beb0) so roll back to version 1.3.35 or lesser might also be needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by one of the maintainers [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/support-requests/41/#7ecd/beb0)

> This is a result of a problem with the
> procedure that I used to build GraphicsMagick 1.3.36 for Windows. I
> should have re-configured the project from scratch but instead I used
> existing project files

I rolled back to version 1.3.35 and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent 4.5 hours working to solve this issue. I am using the npm module pdf2pic, which depends on graphicsmagick. I was able to get it to work by using graphicsmagick version 1.3.35 and ghostscript version 9.52. I had tried with various combinations of later versions of both programs, but received the "No decode delegate for this image format" error. It was also necessary to add graphicsmagick to "path", but not necessary with ghostscript